# Reading Excel sheet using jxl is not working more than 255 rows

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I try to read the Excel sheet which is old format using jxl jar, it works fine but after 255 row it throws error :

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 255
```

I cant read with `Poi jar` because of it is in old format, Any help much appreciated!

Below is java code snippet given below:

```
 public HashMap<String, Float> readAllRowsOnePoint(String path, String sheetname) throws BiffException, IOException {
    System.out.println("Path download" + path);
    FileInputStream fs = new FileInputStream(path);
    Workbook wb = Workbook.getWorkbook(fs);
    Sheet sheet = wb.getSheet(sheetname);
    // To get the number of rows present in sheet
    int totalNoOfRows = 500;
    System.out.println("The rows count is " + totalNoOfRows);
    HashMap<String, Float> map = new HashMap<>();
    for (int row = 2; row < totalNoOfRows; row++) {
        try {
            Cell dateCell = null;
            Cell psidCell = null;
            Cell nameCell = null;
            Cell quantityCell = null;
            Cell billingCell = null;

            try {
             dateCell = sheet.getCell(0, row);
             psidCell = sheet.getCell(1, row);
             nameCell = sheet.getCell(2, row);
             quantityCell = sheet.getCell(8, row);
             billingCell = sheet.getCell(10, row);
            } catch(Exception e){
                //  e.printStackTrace();
            }
        String date = dateCell.getContents().trim();
        String psid = psidCell.getContents().trim();
        String name = nameCell.getContents().trim();
        String quantity = quantityCell.getContents().trim();
        String billing = billingCell.getContents().trim();

        System.out.println();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error in row " + row + " Exception " );
        }
    }
    return map;
}
```

Comment: Did you ever find an answer?  I'm pretty sure that it can handle rows greater than 255 because mine started choking just like yours (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException) but mine is at 1315+

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is on this line:

```
for (int i = 0 ; i < 1000; i++)
```

You can't just insert `1000` because you don't know if every sheet has 1000 rows. Just use the `getRows()` method from the `Sheet` object(As it already shows in the comment above the line):

```
for (int i = 0 ; i < s.getRows(); i++)
```

That way you can't receive an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException because the loop stops after all rows are done.

Comment: it is getting exception and got in catch, code snippet given below :             
           try {
             dateCell = sheet.getCell(0, row);
             psidCell = sheet.getCell(1, row);
             nameCell = sheet.getCell(2, row);
             quantityCell = sheet.getCell(8, row);
             billingCell = sheet.getCell(10, row);
            } catch(Exception e){
                //  e.printStackTrace();
            }

Comment: add there informations to your question. Also show the exact line where the error occurs.

Comment: dateCell = sheet.getCell(0, row);  where it gets error

Comment: Than the cell is empty in that row. But you've changed your code completely.